# How to deserialize avro in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, avro

I have an avro file.
I want to use nodejs to open and read its schema and iterate through its records.
How to do this? The avro libraries I see in nodejs appear to require you to pass in a schema instead of getting the schema out of the .avro file. Also, I want to be able to support arrays, which there does not seem to exist a node library that does (node-avro-io).

My avro/avroschema Contains:

1. A nested field {a:{suba: vala, subb: vala}}.
2. An array field {a:["A","B"]}. node-avro-io does not work.

Error I get with node-avro-io:

```
Avro Invalid Schema Error: Primitive type must be one of: ["null","boolean","int","long","float","double","bytes","string"]; got DependencyNode
```

Comment: node-avro-io allows you to both get the schema from a file or create a file with a schema.

Comment: I have two things 1) A nested field {a:{suba: vala, subb: vala}}. 2) An array field {a:["A","B"]}. node-avro-io does not work. :(

Answer (score 3):

In case you're still looking, you can do this with [`avsc`](https://github.com/mtth/avsc). The code would look something like:

```
var avro = require('avsc');

// To stream the file's records (they will already be decoded):
avro.createFileDecoder('your/data.avro')
  .on('data', function (record) { /* Do something with the record. */ });

// Or, if you just want the file's header (which includes the schema):
var header = avro.extractFileHeader('your/data.avro');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a file, the following code found here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-avro-io will do the trick :

```
var DataFile = require("node-avro-io").DataFile;

var avro = DataFile.AvroFile();

var reader = avro.open('test.avro', { flags: 'r' });
reader.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I have two things 1) A nested field {a:{suba: vala, subb: vala}}. 2) An array field {a:["A","B"]}. node-avro-io does not work.